# Terraform remote state issue for Azureblob in 0.12.x

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-blob-storage, terraform-provider-azure

I am using Azure provider and storing the terraform state in Azure blob storage. Using the below code snippet for this.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "xxxxxx" {
  backend = "azurerm"

  config = {
    container_name       = "terraform-state"
    resource_group_name = "${var.remote_state_resource_group}"
    storage_account_name = "${var.remote_state_storage_account}"
    access_key           = "${var.remote_state_credentials}"
    key                  = "${var.cluster_name}-k8s-worker"
  }

  defaults = {}
}
```

If i run the above code with latest version of terraform version 0.12.x, it is failing with below error. But running the same code with 0.11.x, it is working as expected.

```
Error message:

    Error: Unable to find remote state

  on example2.tf line 20, in data "terraform_remote_state" "xxxxxx":
  20: data "terraform_remote_state" "xxxxxx" {

  No stored state was found for the given workspace in the given backend.
```

Any one faced similar issue in terraform 0.12.x with Azure blob storage.

Comment: You need to provide more info about the terraform code you used.

Comment: Any updates for your question? Does my answer help you solve it? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: What is the reason that you do not give any response and also do not accept?

Answer (score 0):

I think the possible reasons would be here:

1. use the wrong storage account
2. use the wrong container name
3. use the wrong key

All the above reasons will cause the error you got. And the remote state works fine in terraform version 0.12.x.

Comment: Hi Chrles, I am using same storage account, container name and key. it is working for terraform 0.11.x version, not for 0.12.x version. I am using terraform 0.12.12 version, provider code is as below.```provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 1.35"
}

Comment: @DeekshitKumar Can you show more messages about the storage you used to store the state, such as the storage name, container name and the state file name. Also, your Terraform code about all the variables you used in the remote state.

Comment: @DeekshitKumar Any updates for the question? I don't think you can get the solution from SO if you do not reply actively.

Comment: Sorry for delay in response.

Comment: @DeekshitKumar So what is the situation now? Do you solve the problem with my answer? If it works for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue when I have one terraform configuration that stores state in `azurerm` and then I want to use that state in another terraform configuration as a remote `azurerm` data source.

Specifically the issue appears when the first configuration uses terraform workspaces. The `azurerm` backend silently appends a suffix of the form `env:${terraform.workspace}` at the end of the blob key. You must explicitly correct for this in the data source.

If the backend of the first configuration looks like this:

```
terraform {
    backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name  = "rg-myapp"
        storage_account_name = "myappterraform"
        container_name       = "tfstate"
        key                  = "myapp.tfstate"
    }
}
```

The data source of the second configuration must look like this:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "myapp" {
    backend = "azurerm"
    config = {
        resource_group_name  = "rg-myapp"
        storage_account_name = "myappterraform"
        container_name       = "tfstate"
        key                  = "myapp.tfstateenv:${terraform.workspace}"
    }
}
```